# sliding tab not sliding smoothly

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabbed-activity

i have an issue with the tab indicator under the tab titles in my tabbed activity, it's not sliding smoothly it just jumps when i scroll from a fragment to another. i don't really know how to fix this problem. i tried to look for some solutions but i couldn't find any can you please help me? here is my code
if you want any other files just let me know in the comments

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private TabLayout mTabLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.

        //tab Id
        mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        //add tabs
        mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText("Cours"));
        mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText("Quiz"));
        mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText("Info générale"));
        mTabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);

        Pager adapter = new Pager(getSupportFragmentManager(), mTabLayout.getTabCount());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                mTabLayout.setScrollPosition(position, 0, true);
                mTabLayout.setSelected(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

        mTabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        //mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        //tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }
    }
}
```

xml code for the mainActivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:title="@string/app_name">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_1" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_2" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_3" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: It jumps while you are switching tabs via clicking? Or when you are switching tabs via swiping?

Comment: @ReazMurshed both clicking and swiping

Comment: Have you tried `mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);` after setting the adapter in your `ViewPager`? Please check [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)) and let me know the result.

Comment: no but I'll try it right away

Comment: @ReazMurshed it didn't work

Comment: Can you please remove the `TabItem` under `TabLayout` in xml? You are already creating tabs from the code.

Comment: @ReazMurshed i just removed the TabLayout in xml and still jumps not scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Here's code from my app in which I implemented viewpager,

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.chatPageToolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("MyApp");


    //Tabs
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.main_tabPager);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainTabs);
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    setupViewPager(mViewPager);
}

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){

    mSectionPagerAdapter = new SectionPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    blogFragment = new BlogFragment();
    chatFragment = new ChatFragment();
    friendsFragment = new FriendsFragment();

    mSectionPagerAdapter.addFragment(blogFragment,"BLOG");
    mSectionPagerAdapter.addFragment(chatFragment,"CHAT");
    mSectionPagerAdapter.addFragment(friendsFragment,"FRIENDS");
    viewPager.setAdapter(mSectionPagerAdapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
}
```

I don't think you need to add mTabLayout.onTabSelectedListener, just try removing that and try again.
On clicking tabs, it should immediately change the tabs, but on swiping it should swipe smoothly.

Comment: i appreciate the help, but it seems not to be working for me

Comment: Can you please try removing the tab items within tabLayout in xml file.